# Как сделать что бы при клике появлялся блок c увеличенной копией изображения?

Tags: javascript, html, img

Как сделать, что-бы при клике на изображение появлялся блок?

В блоке должна быть увеличенная копия этого же изображения:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
/*
.window {
  display: none;
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.window-image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="card" src="https://assets.quzo.net/site/catalogue/Full/2018/10/asus-rog-strix-z390-f-gaming-ddr4-sdram-dimm-2133-2400-2666-2800-3000-3200-3300-3333-3400-3466--145136.jpg.jpg" />
  <p class="text">описание</p>
</div>

<div class="window">
  <img class="window-image" />
</div>
```

Comment: В чем сложность? Клик по изображению, взяли значение его атрибута `src` и присвоили его такому же атрибуту элемента `.window-image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const card = document.querySelector(".card")

const handleClick = () => {
  const wi = document.querySelector(".window-image")
  const card_src = card.getAttribute("src")
  wi.setAttribute("src", card_src)
  wi.closest(".window").style.display = "block"
}

card.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.window-image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="card" src="https://assets.quzo.net/site/catalogue/Full/2018/10/asus-rog-strix-z390-f-gaming-ddr4-sdram-dimm-2133-2400-2666-2800-3000-3200-3300-3333-3400-3466--145136.jpg.jpg" />
  <p class="text">описание</p>
</div>

<div class="window">
  <img class="window-image" />
</div>
```